# Does checking count-- in a for loop cancels the loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, count

Sry I'm new to C language.
Can someone help me understand what happens in the "for" loop:

When I run this code I get nothing, it's not even entering the loop:

```
for( count=0   ;count--;count--)
{   
    printf("\n%5d", count);
}
```

And when I run this code I get infinite entrances to the loop:

```
for( count=1   ;count--;count--)
{   
    printf("\n%5d", count);
}
```

And when I run this code I get 1 entrance to the loop:

```
for( count=2  ;count--;count--)
{   
    printf("\n%5d", count);
}
```

And so on for every count=**odd number** I get infinite entrances,  and for every count=**even number** I get a limited number of entrances

Can someone explain me why is this hapening?

Comment: Please read this article: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/12/c-loops-examples/, and get back to us if you have more questions after reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you first need to to know exactly what `count--` is. This means that first `count` will be evaluated as part of the condition, then decremented. This means that `count--` is `0` in this case, making the for loop condition evaluate to `0`. After the condition is evaluated, `count` is `-1`, but this doesn't matter because count was `0` during the condition check so the loop never runs.

```
for(count = 0;count--;count--)
{   
    printf("\n%5d", count);
}
```

The next loop starts count at `1`, which means `count--` will be evaluated to `1`, this makes the condition check of the for loop equal to `1`. After the evaluation, count becomes `0`. This means the for loop will enter and print out the message. When the code block ends, the statement `count--` gets executed, setting `count` to `-1`. Then we do the check again. We see that `count--` evaluates to `-1` so we will loop again. After the evaluation, `count` will be set to `-2` and we will enter the for loop again. **This function runs forever because count will always be odd when we get to the for loop check, therefore count can never be `0` and we never break from the loop.**

```
for(count = 1;count--;count--)
{   
    printf("\n%5d", count);
}
```

You should now be able to figure out why the last one only runs once:

```
for( count=2  ;count--;count--)
{   
    printf("\n%5d", count);
}
```

Obviously after the first evalution, `count` gets decremented. Then once the code block gets executed, it is decremented again. Therefore when we get to the conditional check in the for loop, `count` is `0` and we break.

Answer (score 1):

1. `for(left;middle;right)` The middle expression is the condition - an expression which is contextually convertible to bool. This expression is evaluated before each iteration, and if it yields false (or 0 in the case of an int), the loop is exited.
2. `foo--` is a post-operator, which means the value is `foo` is evaluated first and then it is decremented.

Putting these two together,

Case1: Before entering the loop, count-- is evaluated. Count current value is 0. So loop is not executed.

Case2: count-- evaluates to 1, loop is entered once. count-- is executed at the end of the loop. count-- now evaluates to -1 at the beginning of the loop, so loop is executed again, and so on - ad infinitum

Case3: count-- is 2, end of the loop count-- is 0, so loop exits after 1 iteration.